# Plotting a wideform matrix with hues in seaborn stripplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to plot a dataset using stripplot. Here is the head (there are 25 columns):

```
    Labels  Acidobacteria  Actinobacteria  Armatimonadetes  Bacteroidetes  
0       0              0             495              NaN          27859   
1       1              0            1256              NaN          46582
2       0              0            1081              NaN          23798   
3       1              0            2523              NaN          35088   
4       0              0            1383              NaN          19338
```

I have this dataset stored in a pandas DataFrame and can plot it using:

```
   def plot():
    ax = sns.stripplot(data = df)
    ax.set(xlabel='Bacteria',ylabel='Abundance')
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(),rotation=45)
    plt.show()
```

To produce [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO4O1.png).

I would like to set the hues to reflect the `'Labels'` column. When I try:

```
sns.stripplot(x=df.columns.values.tolist(),y=df,data=df,hue='Labels')
```

I get:

```
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 26 to array axis with dimension 830
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I figured it out. I had to rearrange my data by stacking and re-indexing:

```
cols = df.columns.values.tolist()[3:]
stacked = df[cols].stack().reset_index()
stacked.rename(columns={'level_0':'index','level_1':'Bacteria',0:'Abundance'},inplace=True)
```

Which outputs:

```
           index          Bacteria  Abundance
0          0     Acidobacteria   0.000000
1          0    Actinobacteria   0.005003
2          0   Armatimonadetes   0.000000
3          0     Bacteroidetes   0.281586
```

Next I had to create a new column to assign labels to each data point:

```
label_col = np.array([[label for _ in range(len(cols))] for label in df['Labels']])
label_col = label_col.flatten()

stacked['Labels'] = label_col
```

So now:

```
   index         Bacteria  Abundance  Labels
0      0    Acidobacteria   0.000000       0
1      0   Actinobacteria   0.005003       0
2      0  Armatimonadetes   0.000000       0
3      0    Bacteroidetes   0.281586       0
4      0       Chlamydiae   0.000000       0
```

And then plot:

```
def plot():
    ax = sns.stripplot(x='Bacteria',y='Abundance',data=stacked,hue='Labels',jitter=True)
    ax.set(xlabel='Bacteria',ylabel='Abundance')
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(),rotation=45)
    plt.show()
plot()
```

To produce [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85bAo.png).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great answer! But that's a lot of work just to get a wide-form matrix with hue color mixed in...I wish Seaborn has more support for wide-form graphing.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to expand on your answer (actually I will compact it) because this could be done in a "one-liner":

```
# To select specific columns:
cols = ["Acidobacteria", "Actinobacteria", "Armatimonadetes", "Bacteroidetes"]
df.set_index("Labels")[cols]\
    .stack()\
    .reset_index()\
    .rename(columns={'level_1':'Bacteria', 0:'Abundance'})

# If you want to stack all columns but "Labels", this is enough:
df.set_index("Labels")\
    .stack()\
    .reset_index()\
    .rename(columns={'level_1':'Bacteria', 0:'Abundance'})
```

The trick to avoid recreating the `"Labels"` column, is to set it as index *before stacking*.

Output:

```
    Labels        Bacteria  Abundance
0        0   Acidobacteria        0.0
1        0  Actinobacteria      495.0
2        0   Bacteroidetes    27859.0
3        1   Acidobacteria        0.0
4        1  Actinobacteria     1256.0
5        1   Bacteroidetes    46582.0
6        0   Acidobacteria        0.0
7        0  Actinobacteria     1081.0
8        0   Bacteroidetes    23798.0
9        1   Acidobacteria        0.0
10       1  Actinobacteria     2523.0
11       1   Bacteroidetes    35088.0
12       0   Acidobacteria        0.0
13       0  Actinobacteria     1383.0
14       0   Bacteroidetes    19338.0
```